# Error running 'filename'. The system cannot find the file specified (PyCharm)

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.5

I have a PyCharm project on my Windows, where I am able to run most `.py` files by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + F10` (or running the debugger). In one of the files however I get the error

> ```
> Error running 'test':
> Cannot run program  "\opt\anaconda\bin\python" (in directory "..."): CreateProcess error=2, the system cannot find the file specified.`
> ```

The `test.py` file right now only contains `print('hello')`

I can do this for the other files, and using 'Execute selection in console' also works fine. Given I am on a Windows machine the `"\opt\anaconda\bin\python"` part looks suspicious, but I don't know how to fix it.

Any help?

---

Copying the content to another file (e.g. `test_2.py`) 'fixes' the problem, but since this is a collaborative project this isn't viable.

Comment: is test_2.py in the same project?

Comment: Yes `test_2.py` is in the same folder as `test.py`.

Comment: do you run both files from the same Pycharm project?

Comment: if the files are run from different Pycharm projects you may be using different interpreters File->Settings->Project: yourName->Project Interpreter

Comment: Sorry, both files are run from the same PyCharm project.

Answer (score 7):

I think your case is cause by some project environment has changed.
I suggest your open the workspace.xml which located in .idea\, check the parameters in it.

or you can delete the directory ".idea" and re-create the project locate in the original path.

Hope it work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in PyCharm IDE and Windows after adding new libraries and some changes.

I recreated Run/Debug Configurations with these steps (Instead of recreating the whole of project!):

1. Select Edit Configurations... from top panel in PyCharm IDE
   [image]
2. Select these files and press delete for deleting them
   [image]
3. Recreate these files likes this images:

   Click green arrow or press `Ctrl + Shift + F10`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I had to do:

- Check the .idea/workspace.xml for any old venv references (there are several tags like "SDK_HOME" which store the path to the venv) and update as necessary
- Check the .idea/RunConfigurations for any run configs and update them (or delete and recreate as you like)

Answer (score 1):

when I installed the pycharm I had the same issue. for this, you really need to understand the concept of the virtual environment. this error comes because you run the file in another directory in which you do not create any virtual environment.
let's say you create a virtual environment in any folder located at the desktop now you run the files in any other folder located in /user/AppData/any_folder then it will show the error that the system can't find the file specified.
So be sure you run in a file in the same folder in which you created a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after downloading a project from GitHub. It ended up being a configuration problem.
Creating a new project on PyCharm, pasting the code in it, and using your configuration should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the directory in Pycharm IDE by editing the file configuration.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Pycharm project window]

This happens when you try to open a `.py` file instead of an environment. To avoid this error, first, click: **File > Open > PycharmProjects > your_environment_name**

For example, when you create a Django project, you create an environment first that is a folder including the project and app folder.